# Google Geocode API returns same result for different locations

Tags: php, android, ios, google-api, google-geocoding-api

Google Geocode API returns same result for below locations, whereas the distance between them is 3.4 miles as shown on [Google maps](https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/Perkins+Restaurant+&+Bakery,+5002+E+Fowler+Ave,+Tampa,+FL+33617,+United+States/Rodeway+Inn,+210+E+Fowler+Ave,+Tampa,+FL+33612,+United+States/@28.0641548,-82.4475756,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x88c2c7c57bb53bb9:0xbdb0da3eb443aacf!2m2!1d-82.401316!2d28.054877!1m5!1m1!1s0x88c2c72376c06209:0xa80b6e107e82e586!2m2!1d-82.457324!2d28.054805).

```
Perkins Restaurant %26 Bakery, E Fowler Ave, Tampa, FL, United States
Rodeway Inn, E Fowler Ave, Tampa, FL, United States
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Perkins%20Restaurant%20%26%20Bakery,%20E%20Fowler%20Ave,%20Tampa,%20FL,%20United%20States&sensor=true

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=rodeway%20inn,%20E%20fowler%20ave,%20tampa&sensor=true

Responses are exactly same. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in `Geocode` API. I have reported a bug to google web services.